# Установка Laravel

Tags: laravel

Помогите пожалуйста, устанавливаю ларавел, перед этим поставил php, после установил Composer и дальше ларавел командой composer global require laravel/installer.После,создал папку, куда положить проекты и в ней вызвал командную строку и прописал laravel new blog.  Но дальше никак не могу запустить саму локалку так как выдает ошибку.Прошу помощи,первый раз устанавливаю и не знаю уже где искать решение,перерыл что мог

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:\lara\blog/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\lara\blog\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\lara\blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\lara\blog\artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\lara\blog\artisan on line 18
```

---

Вот новые ошибки при попытке подтянуть файлы с композера

```
No lock file found. Updating dependencies instead of installing from lock file. Use composer update over composer install if you do not have a lock file.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php8\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: в папке проекта наверное надо в консоли выполнить `composer install` чтоб композер подтянул нужные пакеты

Comment: Не помогло.Вывело новые ошибки

Comment: Какие?..........

Comment: Вы сначала расширения для PHP поставьте, какие требует Laravel, а потом запускайте композер. А лучше прочитайте нормально документацию. Там написано, что и как устанавливается.